What is the difference between args and kwargs in function definitions?
What is the difference between args and kwargs in function definitions?
difference with explanation and at what time it is important to use one of these keywords give the important uses with examples explain it briefly .

The args stands for arguments that are passed to the function whereas kwargs stands for keyword arguments which are passed along with the values into the function.

args (Non-keyword Arguments/Positional Arguments) –
*args allows a function to accept any number of positional arguments i.e. arguments that are non-keyword arguments, variable-length argument list.

kwargs (Keyword Arguments) –
**kwargs is a special syntax that allows us to pass a variable length of keyword arguments to the function.


Example for args:
def fruits(*args):
    print(args)

fruits('Apple', 'Banana', 1234)

Output:
('Apple', 'Banana', 1234)

Example for kwargs:
def fruits(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        print("{} -> {}".format(key, value))    # OR print(f'{key} -> {value}')

fruits(Apple = 'Red', Banana = 'yellow', numbers = 1234)

Output:
Apple -> Red
Banana -> yellow
numbers -> 1234

